# reusing home directory

Tags: linux, home

I am using linux mostly for programming in python/go/C++ from vim in a shell. It always takes me sometime to set my environments right when installing a new machine. Any tips on how I can reuse an existing home directory set up that I like on a new machine?

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include additional context. Right now your question is very vague. What have you tried and what errors have you encountered?

Comment: It sounds like you want dotfile management, there are many solutions available so use your favorite search engine to check them all out.  It looks like [GitHub has put up some information about dotfile management](https://dotfiles.github.io) that seems interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options I have used are:

1. Have your `/home` or `/home/user` directory located on its own partition in your hard drive. Whenever you install a new Linux distro, create a user with the same UID as your other systems, and mount your `/home` partition.
2. Similar to option 1, keep all configuration files on its own partition or flash drive and install them where necessary.
3. Keep all your configuration files on github (or something similar), and download them on new systems.